# WSO2 with Rabbit MQ - WARNING: EPRs are NULL. Transport configuration may be incorrect

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2-esb

I created a proxy using RabbitMQ and on the Dashboard screen enpoint area shows:
**WARNING: EPRs are NULL. Transport configuration may be incorrect**

Here is my configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="RabbitMqProxy"
       transports="rabbitmq"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
      </inSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="rabbitmq:/RabbitMqProxy?rabbitmq.server.host.name=199.53.215.101&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=intraday.oms.message;rabbitmq.exchange.name=test-topic"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">intraday.oms.message</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.virtual.host">/carbon</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">test-topic</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I can't figure what's wrong but when i follow the windows sample i can't receive any message in the subscriber side and maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Hi Lucas, Did you enable RabbitMq transportReceiver in axis2.xml? (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport#RabbitMQAMQPTransport-InstallingtheRabbitMQAMQPTransport)

Comment: Yes it's enabled as it follows:
   `<transportReceiver name="rabbitmq" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQListener">
      <parameter name="AMQPConnectionFactory" locked="false">
         <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name" locked="false">199.53.215.101</parameter>
         <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port" locked="false">5672</parameter>
         <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name" locked="false">guest</parameter>
         <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password" locked="false">guest</parameter>
      </parameter>
   </transportReceiver>`

Comment: My mistake. I should've asked about the transportSender, but I guess you've configured that part as well. I could find a blog post where it says that the installation of the transport configurations for RabbitMQ did not work and the jars had to be manually copied. Could you check `repository/components/lib` folder for `axis2-transport-rabbitmq-amqp*.jar` and `amqp-client*.jar`? (https://luispenarrubia.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/integrate-wso2-esb-and-rabbitmq-using-amqp-transport/)

Comment: Just checked hoping for this but they are there:
**amqp-client_3.3.4.wso2v1.jar 
axis2-transport-rabbitmq-amqp_1.1.0.wso2v9.jar**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RabbitMQ consumers `rabbitmq.server.virtual.host` is not parameter of proxy, but parameter of Connection Factory.

So, you should make additional connection factory in axis2.xml:

```
<transportReceiver name="rabbitmq" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQListener"‌​>
    <parameter name="AMQPConnectionFactory" locked="false">
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name" locked="false">199.53.215.101</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port" locked="false">5672</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name" locked="false">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password" locked="false">guest</parameter>
    </parameter> 
    <parameter name="AMQPConnectionFactoryCarbon" locked="false">
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name" locked="false">199.53.215.101</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port" locked="false">5672</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.virtual.host">/carbon</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name" locked="false">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password" locked="false">guest</parameter>
    </parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

and change parameter list of your proxy to the follows:

```
<parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">intraday.oms.message</parameter>
<parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactoryCarbon</parameter>
<parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">test-topic</parameter>
```